# Does C++ compile to assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, compilation

Does C++ code compile to assembly code? If we have C++ code, will we be able to get assembly code?

Comment: re: the part about seeing the assembly: See [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for tips on making it nicer to read for humans.  And also **Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk: [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)**

Comment: Re: the compiler-construction aspect: [Does a compiler always produce an assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14039843)

Answer (score 38):

The vast majority of C++ compilers will convert the C++ source into object files (machine code with enough control information to be linked into an executable). They *may* actually generate assembly language as an interim step and even use  a separate assembler for processing  the assembler source, but you'll generally never see that. For example, you have to actually go out of your way to get `gcc` to generate assembly code (.s file) by using the `-S` flag. Normally, you would never see the assembly.

But the C++ standard doesn't mandate the final form that's output from the compiler, just that the code has to behave in a certain way when you run it.

In fact, the earliest C++ "compilers" actually generated C source code and then compiled that.

You can have your C++ compiler generate object code, Java byte code, or even GWBASIC, should you be feeling masochistic.

Comment: Very informative, just a question, how to compile C++ code to Java bytecode?

Comment: Well, you would have to write a compiler to do that. Sorry, I didn't mean to imply there were compilers out there to do that, just that it was both possible and standards-compliant to write one.

Comment: MSVC can compile to MSIL, which is conceptually similar to Java bytecodes.

Comment: @paxdliabo :-/ I thought it would be something to brag about as a C++ programmer! @MSalters both managed and unmanaged code is translated to MSIL?

Comment: @MSalters, MSIL is not conceptually similar to JVM - it allows unsafe pointer arithmetics, and there are mixed mode assemblies. But, it is certainly possible to compile C++ to JVM, with a significant performance penalty, of course.

Comment: Just because you don't _see_ gcc outputting assembly sourcefiles by default doesn't mean it's _not created_. Just run `gcc -v ...` and have a close look (yes that means `gcc` uses/creates _temporary files_, and one of them is the _assembly source_). To be precise: at least `gcc` will _always_ create the assembly sourcefile (and invoke the assembler on it), but the default behaviour is to _cleanup_ and remove those "intermediates".

Comment: You know this really brings up an important question: would it be practical and useful to develop an open-source "translation" package where people who want to translate, say, Java into Ruby, or C++ into Java, could use a compiler to do it instead of hiring developers to re-write it manually.  Does anything like that even exist?

Comment: @emery, those things have been around for a _long_ time, such as p2c for Pascal, f2c for Fortran, even the original CFRONT C++ compiler output C code.

Comment: The sane compiler authors compile to assembly, then call the assembler, gcc, msvc, etc.  they do NOT compile directly to object code nor directly to a binary.  So the correct statement is the vast majority compile to assembly language, which was the OP's question...

Comment: they will use an internal "language"/structure that is a binary, some can export that (llvm) easily and even support that as in input to a tool to generate assembly code.  llvm added a beta feature to go to object rather than assembly language.

Answer (score 24):

Your code has to be understood by the machine, and, as it is not interpreted nor running in a VM, it is first transformed in assembly. You can get this assembly code by using the `-S` flag in your g++ compile options (as long as you are using g++ of course).

```
g++ -S -o file.s file.cpp
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the compiler. There are no real rules regarding what C++ compiles into, except at some point it should be able run on a computer. Most compilers have a switch to compile to assembly.

With `gcc` you can add `-S` to compile into a `.asm` file.

For visual studio see: http://codegem.org/2008/10/generate-assembly-from-c-code-in-visual-studio

Comment: Your link is dead.