# What is the need to generate ASM code in gcc, g++

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, g++

To narrow down my question, let me describe my assumption and the experiment that I did...

***My assumption:*** A code written in assembly language will run much faster than its C/C++ counterpart and also the executable size to be much smaller than that generated from C/C++ code.

The experiment: I wrote the below program in to bin2dec.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int binary, decimal, reminder, exp;
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<10000; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<1000; j++)
        {
            binary = 11000101;

            exp = 1;
            decimal = 0;

            while(binary != 0)
            {
                reminder = binary % 10;
                binary = binary / 10;
                decimal = decimal + reminder * exp;
                exp *= 2;
            }   
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then generated the ASM code for it `gcc -S bin2dec.c -o bin2dec.s`

After that I compiled both the files as below

```
gcc bin2dec.c -o bin2dec_c
gcc bin2dec.s -o bin2dec_s
```

Test 1: Found out some internal details of both the files

```
[guest@localhost ASM]$ size bin2dec_c bin2dec_s
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    951     252       4    1207     4b7 bin2dec_c
    951     252       4    1207     4b7 bin2dec_s
```

Result: Both are exactly same...

Test 2: Executed the files and calculated the time taken

```
[guest@localhost ASM]$ time ./bin2dec_c
real    0m1.724s
user    0m1.675s
sys     0m0.002s

[guest@localhost ASM]$ time ./bin2dec_s
real    0m1.721s
user    0m1.676s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Result: Both are same. Some time the executable generated from ASM ran slower :-(

So the question is, whether my assumptions were wrong?
If not, what mistake I did so that both the executables bin2dec_c and bin2dec_s ran at the same speed?
Is there any better way to get ASM code from a C/C++ program or I should rewrite all the logic from the scratch in ASM to gain the advantage of speed and program size?

Comment: Who said that it was "required to do so"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Compilers don't (generally) go directly from high-level source to machine code, they'll transform into some syntax tree, transform that to some intermediate representation, generate assembly from that and pass the resulting code to an assembler and linker.

Comment: If you don't need the assembly, don't use it. What's the problem?

Comment: Sometimes it's useful for human to look at the ASM instead of having to disassemble the exe

Comment: You forgot the `-O2` option to `gcc`

Comment: GCC 5.2 is compiling with `gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S bin2dec.c`  your code into an empty program (equivalent to `int main() {return 0;}` ....)

Answer (score 5):

It is an old tradition (in the 1970s on early Unix systems, the machine was so small that it was simpler to generate some assembler file), and some compilers can generate directly object files or machine code; probably some recent version of [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/), or [TinyCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) (for C only: fast compilation time, but very slow executable!) perhaps some proprietary XLC compiler from IBM, and some people amongst the GCC community are thinking about that (notably for [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)).

However, **generating an assembler file is often easier for compiler developers**. And since most of the compiler work happens in [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) passes (which are *transforming some internal representations* in the compiler), losing a few milliseconds to start the assembler is not very important.

With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `gcc -time` and `gcc -ftime-report` (and of course your usual optimization flags, e.g. `-O2`) to understand where the compiler spends its time. It is never in the assembler...

You might sometimes find useful to look into the generated assembler file. Compile your `foo.cc` C++11 file with `g++ -O2 -Wall -S -fverbose-asm -std=c++11 foo.cc` then look (with some editor or pager) into the generated `foo.s` assembler file.

You could even compile with `g++ -fdump-tree-all -O2` and get hundreds of compiler dump files from [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) explaining what transformations the compiler did on your code.

BTW today's (superscalar, pipelined) processors (the ones in your desktop, your laptop, your tablet, your server) are so complex that in practice a compiler can optimize better than a human programmer. So practically speaking **the assembler code produced by an *optimizing* compiler** from some realistically sized C code (e.g. a C source file of a few hundred lines) **is** often **faster than what an experimented assembler human programmer can code** in a few weeks (less than a thousand assembler lines). In other words **your assumption** (that code human-written in assembler is faster/better than code human-written in C and compiled by a good *optimizing* compiler) **is *wrong*** *in practice*.

<sup>(BTW, an optimizing compiler is permitted to transform your `bin2dec.c` program, which has no observable side-effects, e.g. no input and output, into an empty program, and [GCC 5.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) does that with `gcc -O2` !!)</sup>

Read also about the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). There is a intrinsic limitation in what optimizing compilers or [static program analyzers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) can achieve.

Comment: Being able to generate assembly code is important to understand the generated code and debug possible compiler errors. Going to the extra effort to be able to directly produce machine code without going through assembly is not necessary, and that's probably some compiler vendors avoid bothering.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: more importantly, you can have compiler options like gcc/clang's `-fverbose-asm`, where the compiler will add comments to the asm based on how it decided to generate that asm.  (e.g. which source variable name is being loaded into a register).  You couldn't easily do that just compiling to machine code and then disassembling.

Comment: modern out-of-order CPUs are actually a lot easier to optimize for than in-order superscaler / pipelined CPUs like Pentium (586) or Atom (or in-order RISC machines).  There can be small effects from scheduling instructions, but mainly you just need to expose parallelism, and thinking about the dependency chains you're creating is not far removed from thinking about the data flow you need to keep track of to write the code at all.

Answer (score 3):

> **Assumption**: A code written in assembly language will run much faster than its
>   C/C++ counterpart and also the executable size to be much smaller than
>   that generated from C/C++ code.

Assembly language is just a text representation for machine code.

With a few caveats, you can disassemble a binary, and re-assemble that source back into the same binary.  Apparently this is truly possible for ARM, but x86 asm dialects don't have syntax to represent different encodings of the same instruction.  e.g. forcing use of a 4-byte offset in a `jmp` instruction in the PLT (Procedure Linking Table), where the jump targets will be patched later.

---

Your experiment made two **identical binaries**.  gcc going directly from C to an executable internally makes an asm source file and assembles it.  You just split up the process so you could get your hands on the compiler-generated asm.

**Hand-written** assembly code is always at least as good as compiler output.  You can always start with compiler output and look for improvements.  In rare cases, there won't be any improvements possible.
Simply **observing** the compiler-generated asm during the compile process doesn't do anything to improve it, though!  Plug your code into http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to see the output with various different compilers (or even for ARM or PPC, which is interesting for `std:atomic` code, to see what happens on a weakly-ordered arch)

---

Since you compiled with no optimizations, there are certainly huge improvements to be made.  I'd start with the output of `gcc -O3 -march=native -fverbose-asm -masm=intel -S`

---

It's *very* rare for compiler output to be truly optimal, though, even for short sequences.  Where compilers have the advantage on humans is in keeping track of a whole lot of source code at once, and making optimizations based on stuff they can prove across functions.  (Such whole-program optimizations would be too brittle to maintain in source code by humans.)  So compilers can taking advantage of stuff that happens to be true in this build, but isn't part of the design of the functions being compiled.

Compilers almost always do a *good* job, but extremely rarely a *great* job.  What's important is that it's a *good enough* job, and the code runs fast, even if it uses more instructions than needed.  Usually stuff like branch mispredicts, cache misses, and dependency chains are bottlenecks, and CPUs are wide enough to handle the extra instructions compilers tend to use without significant slowdowns.  With hyperthreading, doing the same work with fewer instructions is a bigger advantage.

For a concrete example, see the compiler outputs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fastest-way-to-clamp-an-integer-to-the-range-0-255, and compare that with my [probably-optimal hand-written asm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34074838/224132).  I tried to get gcc to generate similarly optimal output, but with no success.  It either used multiple branches or two cmov instructions (which would make the no-clamping fast-path slow), rather than the branch for clamping or not, then a cmov for clamp to zero or clamp to max.

Comment: Hi Peter,Basile, Thank you for your time and effort in answering my queries. What I learned is, my initial assumption was wrong. However, I just came across http://www.menuetos.net/ where people are trying to develop entire OS on assembly language. This only triggered the above question in my mind.