# What is the corresponding or closest concept in C for "variable indirection" in bash?

Tags: c, bash, programming-languages

I am reading [What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/bash-indirect-expansion-please-explain) about variable indirection in bash (the general case, not exceptional case).

I am more familiar with C than bash.

Is there a corresponding concept in C  for "variable indirection" in bash?

Or what is the closet concept in C  to "variable indirection" in bash?

Comment: Can you please stick to one language at a time please? Python and C and C++ are all different enough.

Comment: The question you linked to talks about specific exceptions to indirect expansion. Did you want to know about equivalents to those exceptions, or to the original concept of indirect expansion? You are basically asking about *introspection* here, the ability to access names in the code.

Comment: Thanks, @MartijnPieters. I change to limit to C at first. But I am afraid if I  can ask the same question again except for a different langauge. I am asking about the general case, not exceptional case.

Comment: I don't think C has such a concept; it doesn't have introspection capabilities at least.

Comment: Does C++ or Python have? In any of the languages, is the name of a variable served as the address of the variable?

Comment: Python has. `globals()` and `locals()` give you access to namespaces, reflected as dictionaries. `globals()['foo']` gives you the value of the global variable `foo`, for example.

Comment: can you define what untrospection is?

Comment: @Tim: I improved my answer to give more references. Some languages are able to query something about their own call stack (reflection, introspection, ...)

Comment: _"I am asking about the general case"_ That's a little suspect. Which practical problem could you possibly have that requires knowing this (whatever "this" is) for multiple languages?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: "introspection" is  the ability of a program to examine the type or properties of an object at runtime (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection), while "variable indirection" in bash is to reference the value of a variable using the value of another variable which is the name of the first variable. I don't find them related. Is "variable indirection" in bash an example of "introspection"? Or how are they related?

Comment: @Tim: I always mix up [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) and introspection, because in Python they are often one and the same. You can do what Bash does in Python using reflection; you look up the value associated with a 'variable variable'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks. Could you recommend some general programming language books for concepts including reflection, introspection, ...?

Comment: In the broadest terms, pointers in C are sort of like indirect variables in Bash.  A regular `int` has a value; a pointer to an `int` tells you where you can find the `int` value you want.  A named variable in Bash has a value; an indirect variable reference tells you the name of the variable which contains the value you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, and the concept of variable (and of environment) is *very* different in C, in bash, and in Scheme or Python or Javascript.

You might want to become familiar with some Lisp or Scheme (e.g. read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)) then read Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://pages.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) (explaining in great details about Lisp interpreters & compilers). Read also Scott's [Programming Languages Pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/). Then you'll get a broader view of the notion of variable (and you might study the [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics) and/or the [denotational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) of some programming language).

First, C is a low-level language. It has pointers, pointer arithmetic, address-of operator (unary `&`). Its variables exist only at compile time (at runtime, there are mostly locations in the store -e.g. in heap or on the call stack or in global data segment). Look into [ACSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI/ISO_C_Specification_Language) for describing incompletely some specification of the behavior of some C functions.

On Linux, you could get the address of a *global* variable or function from its name using [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html), and you might get the name of a *global* variable or function from its address using [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html)

Read also about [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) languages (which *C* is not) and [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) (which *C* has not) and [type introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) (which *C* has not; but see [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) in C++).

Some programming languages (but not C) are expliciting & [reifying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29) their environments (mapping variables to values) and their [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). In standard C, the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is not inspectable or introspectable (and that would be useful for [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29)). See GNU libc [backtraces](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) functions (they cannot be written in portable C). Scheme has [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation).

Notice that a language with introspectable call stack could be compiled into C or into C++ (see my [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) DSL as an example), essentially by reifying each call frame into some local `struct` ....

Read also about the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). There is a intrinsic limitation in what optimizing compilers or [static program analyzers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) can achieve (copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34017913/841108) other answer of mine). See also [J.Pitrat's blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) and books about metaknowledge and reflexive/introspective Artificial Intelligence systems.

Comment: Thanks. How  are variable indirection in my post and "introspection" related?

Comment: Because your question is unclear, since the notion of variable and of environment vary *widely* between different languages.

Comment: Thanks. My question was: is "variable indirection" in bash "introspection"? Or how are they related? "introspection" is   the ability of a program to examine the type or properties of an object at runtime, while "variable indirection" in bash is to reference the value of a variable using the value of another variable which is the name of the first variable.